# Recognize a song with a media stream in javascript

Tags: javascript, audio

I was wondering if there is a way to recognize a song based on a media stream, because i want to capture the audio of a tab in google chrome and then know what song it is.

So far the only thing i really found was a song recognizer with an mp3 file, but i was wondering if there is an api or something that i can do it with a stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there actually are a couple of different API's out there, the most popular one (and IMO the best one) being [Echoprint](http://echoprint.me/).

Good luck with your coding!